# Returning zip from DJango view using zip_file: could not find a easy way

Tags: python, django, zip

I want to loop over all files of a folder to make a zip folder

and before make zip, I need to filter row in files
I have found a way to do it, but seems "hack" so I wonder if there is a good solution

for tests, I have 2 files in my folder: file1.csv and file2.csv

original file1.csv

```
field1,field2,filed3
CI-S1-001,1,test1
CI-S1-002,1,test2
```

original file2.csv

```
field1,field2,filed3
ZA-S1-001,1,test3
ZA-S2-002,1,test4
```

filtered_export view function will loop over the 2 files and filter rows based on first field

as user have rigth on 'S1' and 'S3', the 2 rows of file1.csv and only the first row file2.csv will be return and write if zip files and the zip folder will contain 2 files

ZIP file1.csv

```
field1,field2,filed3
CI-S1-001,1,test1
CI-S1-002,1,test2
```

ZIP file2.csv

```
field1,field2,filed3
ZA-S1-001,1,test3
```

```
def filtered_export(request):
    
    # site list available for user
    sites = ['S1','S3']

    ...
    # retrieve the list of all files in study directory excluding 'archives' directory
    listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(path)
    
    # Create zip
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'w')
    
    for file in listOfFiles:
        records = []
        # read the files 
        with open(path + file, newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
            has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read())   
            csvfile.seek(0)
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
            csv_headings = ','.join(next(spamreader))
            
            for row in spamreader:
                for site in sites:
                    if site in row[0]: # filter on substring of the firts field of csv file
                        records.append(','.join(row))

        zip_file.writestr(file, csv_headings+'\n'+'\n'.join(records))
                       
                
    zip_file.close()
        
   
    # Return zip
    response = HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue())
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip-compressed'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+study+'.zip'

    return response
```

Comment: That is a right code but it will be an issue if the files are big as filtration will be slow, you can use something like map(l which be faster and also you can you FileStream as a response handler.

Comment: thanks for replying. I start reading for map() function but filter() would not be more appropriate?